# iterate java HashMap<String,JSONObject> in javascript and fetch values

Tags: javascript, java, json, hashmap

I have created `HashMap`like `HashMap<String,JSONObject>` and put some values in the same like below

```
[
    fruits = {
        "somefruits": ["banana", "apple", "mango"]
    },
    flowers = {
        "someflowers": ["rose", "lotus"]
    }
]
```

now I want fetch these values using javascript and  like if I click on fruits all fruits should display and same for the flowers 
 How can I achieve the same.

**java code**

```
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
obj1.put("somefruits","banana,apple,mango");
JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
obj2.put("someflowers","rose,lotus");

Map<String, JSONObject> data = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();
data.put("fruits",obj1);
data.put("flowers",obj2);
```

I want fetch values in `data` using javascript.... like

**Javascript**

```
function getValues()
{
   var data = <%=data%>;
   //fetch values....???
}
```

Can I convert this hashmap `data` to json and fetch using javascript....??? or Any other way to achive...??

Thanks.

Comment: Please, rewrite your question... you tagged with Java but it seams you are only using javascript. What do you mean with "convert this hashmap to json and fetch using javascript....???" do you have a json, a Hashmap (Java) or a javascript object?

Comment: I have mention that... I created a `HashMap<String,JSONObject>` in java with above values..... and I want to fetch the `HashMap` using javascript.